# How to convert a range score to a letter grade in Python

Tags: python

Prompt: 
    Write a program to prompt for a score between 0.0 and 1.0. If the score is out of range, print an error message. If the score is between 0.0 and 1.0, print a grade using the following table:
    Score   Grade

> = 0.9  A
>   = 0.8  B
>   = 0.7  C
>   = 0.6  D
>       < 0.6   F

```
Script:

   #Given a score, calculates a grade 
   import sys
   #Prompts user for the score
   try: 
       score=input("Enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0: ")
       intscore=float(score)
   except:  
       print("Bad Score")
       sys.exit()

   #Converts string to an integer. User-input is string by default.

   if(score>0 and score <0.6):
       print ("F")
   elif score >= 0.6:
       print ("D")
   elif score >= 0.7:
       print ("C")
   elif score >= 0.8:
       print ("B")
   else:
       print ("A")




ERROR:
   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-25-4ac2f20d04f3> in <module>()
        15 #Converts string to an integer. User-input is string by default.
        16 
   ---> 17 if(score>0 and score <0.6):
        18     print ("F")
        19 elif score >= 0.6:

    TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: Note how you never use `intscore`.

Comment: you correctly changed string to int by `intscore=float(score)`. but not use it in your conditions. just use `intscore` insted of `score` in your conditiones

Comment: Apart from your error the structure of comparisons is flawed: 0.9 is greater than 0.6 so *D* is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the score variable in your logic instead of intscore
`if(score>0 and score <0.6):`
Just replace score with intscore in your If/else statements

```
if (intscore>0 and intscore <0.6):
    print ("F")
elif intscore >= 0.6:
    print ("D")
elif intscore >= 0.7:
    print ("C")
elif intscore >= 0.8:
    print ("B")
else:
    print ("A")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may rewrite as:

```
try: 
    score=float(input("Enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0: "))
    #intscore=float(score)
```